connection between bhakti jnana and karma
Is it true While Karma Yoga, Jyana Yoga, and Bhakti Yoga are often described as distinct paths, they are deeply interconnected, and the Bhagavad Gita teaches that they complement one another and intertwined. If yes explain...
Give me same real examples

It's a popular misinformation that they are dstinct. They are indeed steps on a ladder.

They don't permit wiki article as answer, so posting as comment!   https://hi.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%A4%AF%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%97_%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%80_%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A8_%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%82%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE

Yes, Bhakti without Jnana will be sentimental. No one can remain without performing their respective duties, so they need to be dovetailed into Bhakti by offering their results to Krishna as explained in the Gita.

They are distinct paths but one leads to the other. This is made clear in the following passage from the Devi Bhagavatam:


By My Grace, you will no doubt be able to get the Final Liberation.
Whoever is entirely attached to Me, thinking Me as the Highest, is the
foremost amongst the Bhaktas. I promise that I will certainly deliver
him from this ocean of the world. O King of mountains! Meditation with
Karma and Jñâna with Bhakti will lead one to Me. Only the work alone
will fail to get one to Me. O Himavan! From Dharma arises Bhakti and
from Bhakti arises the Highest Jñâna. What are said in the S'ruti
and Smriti S'astras the Maharsis take that as the Dharma; and what are
written in other S'astras, they take them to be Dharmâbhâsa (the
Shadow or reflection of Dharma).
(from the 39th Chapter of Book 7)

"From Dharma arises Bhakti", in other words, means that performing Karmas according to Dharma leads to Bhakti and which ultimately leads to Jnana (which is considered as the ultimate goal in spirituality). So, all the said paths are connected in this manner.
